# Есть какие-нибудь расширения или библиотеки и т.д., чтобы автоматически применялись стили "грамотно". Как в scss

Tags: css

Допустим есть есть `div`, а в нём текст. Я даю тексту текстовые стили, а расширение "нужные"(что наследуются) стили применяет к диву. Чтобы не было лишних строк в css файле. Вот пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrg6np50/

Я имел ввиду, чтобы преобразовался код как в scss, или наподобие.

Comment: Непонятно почему бы просто не написать `div{color:green}`

Comment: Представьте что весь файл замусорен так, а это потом все рефакторить. Есть что-то наподобие? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Css in js иначе называется jss